# How can i optimize the mysql COUNT() query with many-to-many relationship(through the 3rd table)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, many-to-many

Here is the query that i execute:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT `p`.*
      FROM `shop_products` `p` LEFT JOIN
           `shop_tag_assignments`
           ON `p`.`id` = `shop_tag_assignments`.`product_id` LEFT JOIN
           `shop_tags`
           ON `shop_tag_assignments`.`tag_id` = `shop_tags`.`id`
      WHERE `p`.`status`=1
      GROUP BY `p`.`id`
     ) `c`
```

This query takes about 300 milliseconds(i think it's too long..)

EXPLAIN QUERY:

[EXPLAIN QUERY IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqVY6.png)

DB tables dump:

1k records in **shop_tags** table

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `label` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `shop_tags`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx-shop_tags-slug` (`slug`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `shop_tags`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1162;
COMMIT;
```

Table structure for **shop_tag_assignments**:

224k records in **shop_tag_assignments** table

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_tag_assignments` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `shop_tag_assignments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`tag_id`),
  ADD KEY `idx-shop_tag_assignments-product_id` (`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `idx-shop_tag_assignments-tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  ADD KEY `_index_name` (`product_id`,`tag_id`),
  ADD KEY `__index_name` (`tag_id`,`product_id`);

ALTER TABLE `shop_tag_assignments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk-shop_tag_assignments-product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `shop_products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk-shop_tag_assignments-tag_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `shop_tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

**Mysql version**:
5.7.16-10-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the subquery.  And don't use backticks so much:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)
FROM shop_products p LEFT JOIN
     shop_tag_assignments sta
     ON p.id = sta.product_id LEFT JOIN
     shop_tags st
     ON sta.tag_id = st.id
WHERE p.status = 1;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `shop_products(status, id)`.

Next, your query is counting the number of rows returned by the inner subquery after aggregation by `p.id`.  You are using `LEFT JOIN`, so nothing is being filtered out.  That means that the joins are really redundant.  I think this does the same thing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM shop_products p 
WHERE p.status = 1;
```

This should be much faster than your version . . . however, your version is pretty fast so you might not notice a really big difference.

Comment: "LEFT JOIN" are required in this query, because I want to filter the products by their tag names. Sorry for not clarifying that in advance.
Maybe there is another way to count quantity of products and filtering them by their tag names respectively?

Comment: That is not what this question asked but you can use `where` in the first query.